# load a PostGIS layer into a QGIS map

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, plugins

I'm trying to write a plugin that among athor things adds a layer from a database.
Here is my code:

```
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        # set host name, port, database name, username and password
        uri.setConnection("geoerpdev2", "5432", "LAIS_SPACIAL", "postgres", "Passsword")
        # set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally
        # subset (WHERE clause)

        uri.setDataSource("spacial", "parcels", "geom","cell_code=3030404")
        if uri:
            print (uri)

        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "parcels", "postgres")
        if not vlayer.isValid():
            print (uri)
            print (vlayer)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([vlayer])
```

When I change setDataSource as sugested to:

```
uri.setDataSource("spacial", "parcels", "geom","\"cell_code\"='3030404'")
```

Still nothing happens.

In the python console this is what is printed:

```
<qgis._core.QgsDataSourceUri object at 0x000002F5CA5C9EE8>
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000002F5CA5E8C18>
dbname='LAIS_SPACIAL' host=geoerpdev2 port=5432 user='postgres' password='Password' table="spacial"."parcels" (geom) sql=cell_code=3030404
```

This is the info about the layer when I load it manually:
[image]

I based my code on this example [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html).

Can someone detect why nothing is loading?

Comment: Did my answer sort this out?

Comment: It did not sadly:\

Comment: Oh, bugger... does it work without the filter?

Comment: It'd be good to get the filter working, though! At lease we know that part is right ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the quotes are important. Try it with this:

```
uri.setDataSource("spacial", "parcels", "geom","\"cell_code\"='3030404'")
```